# How do I view joins in my raw sql in django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a model that stores raw sql in one of its fields like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    raw_sql = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # other fields
```

Now I want to see that on tables is the join being applied. I am doing this to prevent unnecessary joins while executing these queries. Is there any way, I can see the models from the raw_sql?

Comment: What do you mean by "join being applied"? If you're just storing SQL in a text field, then it's just data in the database, it's not doing anything by being there.

Comment: Yes I am just storing the sql in db, but I intend to execute it later on.

Comment: There's likely a better solution to this. Executing raw sql is considered dangerous, so allowing arbitrary SQL to be stored and executed should _really_ be avoided. Can't you use the django ORM (and it's security/safety measures) to achieve whatever it is you're doing?